# SQL Server Agent Job - GetDate() is not loading the expected result

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I've a SQL Agent Job with a Insert Into Statement and one of the columns is calculated with this code:

```
dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate() ), 0)
```

With this column I wanto to get the job execution datetime with the hour truncated. But I run the query at 10am and I was expecting to see in the table the following datetime:

```
2017-06-14 11:00:00.000
```

But in my table all the records have the following datetime:

```
2017-06-14 00:00:00.000
```

The query that I've in SQL Agent Job is very simple:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA (ID, Transaction_Desc, Transaction_Date, Purchase_Amount, Job_Date)
SELECT purchase_id,
       purchase_desc,
       purchase_date,
       purchase_amount,
       dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate() ), 0)
FROM Src_Table
```

Why is getting the time **00:00:00.000**?

Many thanks!

Comment: Seems like your code is fine

Comment: Forgive the dumb question.  Did you confirm Job_Date is a datetime ?

Comment: yes is a datetime type

Comment: Where is the Server you are hitting? It could be a time difference from your local time. What does return the "select getdate()" query?

Comment: I am in GMT+5.5 and I ran `SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate() ), 0)` . local time : 16:02. output : 16:00 . Point is, why should you expect 11AM when you ran it at 10AM ?

Comment: If I run the code of my SQL Agent Job Steps manually it works fine but when I execute all the job it returns the wrong date

Comment: Either you are looking at the wrong table or something else is happening. If I had to guess, somewhere your column is set using "day" as the datepart rather than hour. And that would explain the effective absence of time in your values. E.g., 

`select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate() ), 0)`
`select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate() ), 0)`

A trigger perhaps?

Comment: If I execute the query using SSIS it works fine... probably I need to put all this statements on SSIS